# Error Number of index partitions must be in range 1..256 when creating new crawl component

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, search, crawling, search-scope, crawl

I have created Search Service Application using powershell script as I get error when I used Central Administration.

Search Service Application was created without any problem,  but crawl component and index partition was not created by default. So I try to create Crawl component and Index partition  using Central Administration GUI features. But When I click "Apply topology changes" I got following error :

```
Errors were encountered during the configuration of the Search Service Application. 

System.InvalidOperationException: Number of index partitions must be in range 1..256. at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.TopologyExport.QueryTopologySettings.Validate() at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.TopologyExport.TopologySettings.Validate(SearchServiceApplicationType applicationType) at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.TopologyCommitJobDefinition.Create(SearchServiceApplication searchApp, TopologySettings topology) at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.SearchConfigWizard.UpdateSearchApp() at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.SearchConfigWizard.ProvisionSearchServiceApplication() at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.SearchConfigurationJobDefinition.ExecuteTimerJob()
9/3/2013 1:43:15 PM
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: what error did you get, when  you tried to create Search Service Application using Central Administration?

Comment: Assuming you are talking about SharePoint 2013. What eror are you getting from CA? It sounds like you have another underlying issue. What code are you using for provisioning the index partition?